# perl split function using two delimiters

Tags: perl

I'm reading in a file in Perl and I want to split the values based on two delimiters.

```
col1        col2
uc011nbb.2  NM_001039567
uc004fuo.4  NM_001006120
uc011nbc.2  NM_001006121
uc010nwz.3  NM_001006121
```

col 1 and col2 are seperated by tabs, so I normally use this:

```
my @cols = split(/\t/);
```

however, I want to split col1 also on '.'. How can I modify my split function for that?

Comment: `my @cols = split(/[.\t]/); `

Comment: Assuming your 'col2' isn't ever going to contain a `.` of course!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`character class`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes) to encode both possibilities:

```
split /[.\t]/;
```

As @Sobrique notes above, you should ensure that `.` will not ever be in any of your column names before using it as a delimiter.

Example:

```
say foreach split /[.\t]/, "this is some.text that has\ttwo delimiters";
this is some
text that has
two delimiters
```

Comment: If the second column might contain dots, use `split /[\t.]/, $_, 3` to never split to more than 3 values.